# Protecting website from CSRF by sending the validatecookie as parameter?

Tags: php, ajax, cookies, csrf

What I've understood, **CSRF**-Attacks works like this:

1. When you check if a user is logged in to your website you check if a **validate cookie** is set and matched to the database.
2. A 3rd part sends the user to a site in your website, for example **"changePassword.php"**
3. The site **"changePassword.php"** will check if the user is logged in by checking the cookie is matching to the database, if it is set, the page will "change the password". 
   It is set since you logged in to the website in another tab therefore the password will be changed.

To prevent this websites are using a **Token** that is generated random by the webpage, and stored as a session, then your webpage sends this **token** with the request, as a parameter. Since that make the website know the user really visited the website and performed the action.

### The question is:

Instead of sending a **token** as a *parameter*. Can you just send the **logged in cookie** as a *parameter*?

Since cookies are webiste-specific, I can not see a way another page would be able to send this cookie as a parameter to your website.

Comment: No, the outcome is not the same. Cookies do not help in the situation you sketch, since the browser would send the cookie anyway, since it matches the domain of your `changePassword.php` script. You need to have some means that is _not_ automatically provided, but manually. Something 3rdparty scripts cannot guess or take for given.

Comment: the website create csrf and xsrf key and set those on the page and those value send to destination page. because of the site created the key and store it, it will be able to check if the value are true or not.

Comment: If someone sends a 'change password' request then it may be worthwhile asking them to re-enter the username and password so you know it is the the 'owner' doing it 'real time'?

Comment: @RyanVincent Yes, this will happen in the page, but then an ajax call will be sent to a seperate php page, wich will change the password in the database. This ajax call need to know the request is sent from the website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can, assuming "logged in cookie" is a cryptographically secure session identifier.

This method of CSRF defence is known as [Double Submit Cookies](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Double_Submit_Cookies):

> Double submitting cookies is defined as sending a random value in both
>   a cookie and as a request parameter, with the server verifying if the
>   cookie value and request value are equal.

Normally this value is separate than the session ID, but there is no reason not to use it if your session IDs are static.

In a CSRF attack, the attacker can only submit the victim's cookies to the target site using the victim's browser. There is no way of the attacker actually reading the cookie value, nor a copy of this value set as a POST parameter. So, double submit cookies is a good CSRF defence.

Note that using a GET parameter is not recommended, as this value can be leaked in [the `referer` header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer).

Answer (score 0):

I found out why this wont work, if you send your cookie as a parameter there will always be a way for the attacker to use that (jquery?)function, or similar. Therefore you will always have to get the token from the webpage. You could maybe print the cookie and then get it that way, but it would just be easier to make a session token as an hidden input to the website.

Comment: An attacker can you vanilla JavaScript too. jQuery isn't the new JavaScript. Hidden inputs can also be read (and sent to the attacker with XSS). I would recommend saying "bind a unique value to the user that changes on each request" - ie: a token.